# What is the Windows equivalent of POSIX unistd.h macro STDIN_FILENO?

Tags: c

I know that POSIX defines STDIN as 0, and that

["On program startup, the integer file descriptors associated with the streams stdin, stdout, and stderr are 0, 1, and 2, respectively.  The preprocessor symbols STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO, and STDERR_FILENO are defined with these values in <unistd.h>."](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdin.3.html),

but I am very confused how it works in Windows. I managed to find some clue after a lot of searching, but it only mentions stdio.h (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/low-level-i-o?view=msvc-170). It says the file descriptors are "pre-defined". But where?

PS: Should I just hardcode 0 in my code instead of trying to standardize everything? I mean, POSIX won't change it. Only question is Windows.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle

Comment: Consider whether you can reasonably use standard C functions such as `fread()` and `fwrite()`, which operate on *streams* such as `stdin` and `stdout`, instead of using POSIX functions that operate on file descriptors, such as `read()` and `write()`.

Answer (score 3):

Windows is different than Unix.

If you are using Win32 APIs like ReadFile and WriteFile for i/o on stdio, stdout, or stderr, you invoke [GetStdHandle](https://use%20these%20macros%20with%20%60https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle%60) and pass `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`, `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE`, or `STD_ERROR_HANDLE` to obtain a **handle** for subsequent Win32 operations.

If you are using the posix emulated APIs on Windows, such as `_read` and `_write`, you can safely pass 0, 1, and 2 as stdin, stdout, and stderr file ids. Define your own macos as needed.